# Question regarding a proof of Cauchy Condensation test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

on Wikipedia there is another proof for the cauchy condensation test which has the last step where they say the integral converges iff the sum converges, but I'm not sure if that can be said because the integral test requires the integrand to be decreasing and positive, and I don't think the integrand is necessarily decreasing

[image: Integral test proof]

This is what Wikipedia says, but I also found this note online [here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/CTH/tma226/1718/condensation_note.pdf) which says [image]
I'm not sure about the last step, because what if $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$? Then $2^n f(2^n) = 1$ which is not decreasing. The integral test also works for "non-increasing" functions, but what about $f(n) = c$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$? I'm not sure how you can apply the integral test here.

Comment: I agree with the OP: there are certainly functions $f$ for which $2^yf(2^y)$ alternates between increasing and decreasing, and the circled equivalence won't automatically hold for such functions. I believe one can construct such $f$ that is itself positive and decreasing as well.

Comment: I think youre right about the proof being incorrect, im pretty sure you can construct decrasing functions where $2^nf(2^n)$ Isn't even monotonic. (Ninja'd lol)

Comment: "$f$ is decreasing" means $x<y\implies f(x)\le f(y)$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet But then what about $f(x) = c$? This is decreasing, however $2^n f(2^n)  = 2^n c$ is certainly not decreasing.